# c# datagridview Object reference not set to an instance of an object

Tags: c#, datagridview, row, addition

I'm taking data entered by the user and trying to add them to a datagridview in another form that I created, however, I'm having an

*Object reference not set to an instance of an object.* when I try to add my **first** row,

this is the code below:

```
    monthTrans mt = new monthTrans();
    private void completeBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var todayDate = DateTime.Now;
        //MessageBox.Show(todayDate.ToString());
        var transType = typeLabel.Text;
        var currencySelected = CurrencyList.Text;
        var amount = AmountText.Text;
        var currencyPrice = currencyPriceText.Text;
        var total = totalAmountText.Text;

        var monthlyData = mt.myData;

        monthlyData.Rows.Add(todayDate, transType, currencySelected, amount, currencyPrice, total);

        //open a new window
        mt.Parent = Parent;
        mt.StartPosition = FormStartPosition.CenterParent;
        if (mt.IsDisposed)
              mt = new monthTrans();
        mt.Show();
    }
```

the error appears on "monthlyData.Rows.Add......."

btw, I added in my datagridview form this code below to access it outside that form:

```
    public DataGridView myData
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
```

thanks for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try:

```
private DataGridView _mydata = new DataGridView();
public DataGridView myData
{
    get { return _mydata; }
    set { _mydata = value; } 
}
```

Comment: I made a few changes and works:

        DataGridView theData;
        public monthTrans()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            theData = dataGridView1;
        }

        public DataGridView myData
        {
            get { return theData; }
            set { theData = value; }
        }

thanks for your help